# implementing trace in an xml generation PowerShell script

Tags: powershell, if-statement, while-loop, try-catch, export-to-csv

I'm new to PowerShell, I need to create traces on several steps of the script below.

Here is the csv example (the real one is about a million lines)
I erased a value in the first column in order to do test

```
UCB63_DATENUM;U6618_FILENAME;UF6E8_CANAL;U65B8_IDRP
7/8/19 22:27;;ML;1367091;
9/11/19 23:03;49453878_ZN_LIQRLVPR_A_V_ML.pdf;ML;106440
9/24/19 21:04;497E585B_ZN_LIQRLVPR_A_V_CS.pdf;CS;1536658
2/12/20 22:12;58453B75_ZN_LIQRLVPR_A_V_ML.pdf;ML;1406091
```

First check would be on the whole CSV, to check the right number and names of the column

Then check of an exception or an error during treatment (I think a try/catch)

I've changed things, some of them work other not (I can't find why)

I still have to do a first check on my document (number of columns and name of the column)

If you try the code you'll see in the result of the TITLE (in my xml)  I get a ')' which I was not expecting
And if I erase a value in U65B8_IDRP column the error is not catch and goes into the xml

Here is the code

```
#vARIABLES EN DUR
$FREQUENCE_DECOMPTE     = 'Nom="FREQUENCE_DECOMPTE" Valeur="MENS"'
$LIBELLE_ORGANISME      = 'Nom="LIBELLE_ORGANISME" Valeur="HUMANIS CCN OG"'
$MONTANT_TOTAL          = 'Nom="MONTANT_TOTAL" Valeur="0"'
$POLE                   = 'Nom="POLE" Valeur="1ADP"'
$CODE_ORGANISME         = 'Nom="CODE_ORGANISME" Valeur="1ADP"'

# Paramètre nombre item par xml VALEUR A MODIFIER A 5000
$maxItemsPerXml = 3

#Import du csv et création des différentes collections 
$liste = Import-Csv -path 'c:\temp\testH.csv' -Delimiter ';'
[System.Collections.ArrayList] $DateErrors = @()
[System.Collections.ArrayList] $FileNameErrors = @()
[System.Collections.ArrayList] $CanalErrors = @()
[System.Collections.ArrayList] $NumAssureErrors = @()

#Initiation booléen

foreach($item in $liste)
{
    #Initiation variables booléennes 
    $MyDateIsCorrect = $true
    $MyFileNameIsCorrect = $true
    $MyCanalIsCorrect = $true
    $MyNumAssureIsCorrect = $true

    #Transformations données
    $date = $($item.UCB63_DATENUM -split " ")[0]
    $renommage = % {$item.U6618_FILENAME.Split('.')[0]}

    if([System.String]::IsNullOrEmpty($item.UCB63_DATENUM)) 
        { 
        $MyDateIsCorrect = $false
        $DateErrors.Add($item)
        }

    else   {
            if($date -notmatch "[0-9]{1,2}[\/][0-9]{1,2}[\/][0-9]{1,2}") 
                { 
                $MyDateIsCorrect = $false
                $DateErrors.Add($item) 
                } 
           }
    
    if([System.String]::IsNullOrEmpty($item.U6618_FILENAME)) 
        { 
        $MyFileNameIsCorrect = $false
        $FileNameErrors.Add($item)
        } 
           
    else   { 
             if($item.U6618_FILENAME -notmatch ".+[\.]pdf") 
                { 
                $MyFileNameIsCorrect = $false
                $FileNameErrors.Add($item)
                }
           }      
    
    if([System.String]::IsNullOrEmpty($item.UF6E8_CANAL)) 
        { 
        $MyCanalIsCorrect = $false
        $CanalErrors.Add($item)
        }
    
    if([System.String]::IsNullOrEmpty($item.U65B8_IDRP)) 
        { 
        $MyNumAssureIsCorrect = $false
        $NumAssureErrors.Add($item)
        }



    #Génération output XML
    if($MyDateIsCorrect -and $MyFileNameIsCorrect -and $MyCanalIsCorrect -and $MyNumAssureIsCorrect)
    {
@"
     <Document>
            <Index Nom="TITLE" Valeur="$renommage"/>
            <Index Nom="NO_ASSURE" Valeur="$($item.U65B8_IDRP)"/>
            <Index Nom="DEBUT_PERIODE" Valeur="$RecupDateFinTraitement"/>
            <Index Nom="FIN_PERIODE" Valeur="$RecupDateFin30"/>
            <Index $FREQUENCE_DECOMPTE/>
            <Index $LIBELLE_ORGANISME/>
            <Index $MONTANT_TOTAL/>
            <Index Nom="DATE_GENERATION_DECOMPTE"$RecupDateFinTraitement/>
            <Index $POLE/>
            <Index $CODE_ORGANISME/>
            <Index Nom="ALERTE_MAIL" Valeur="$fin"/>
            <Fichier Nom="$($item.U6618_FILENAME)"/>
        </Document>
"@ 

    # création fichier
    $xmlFile = "C:\Temp\MIG_ERELEVE_MM_$(get-date -f dd-MM-yyyy)_{0:D3}.xml" -f $xmlFileCount
    # création fichier ok
    $CsvColonneEnPlus = import-csv -path 'c:\temp\testH.csv' -Delimiter ';' | Select-Object *,@{Name='Etat';Expression={'OK'}} 

    
    
    # création contenant xml, décla du root node et écriture dans fichier
@"
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Documents Origine="ERELEVE_HUM">
$($XMLItems -join "`r`n")
</Documents>
"@ | Set-Content -Path $xmlFile -Encoding UTF8 

        # Création fichier OK suite traitement
        #$CsvColonneEnPlus = import-csv -path 'c:\temp\testH.csv' -Delimiter ';' | Select-Object *,@{Name='Etat';Expression={'OK'}} | Export-Csv -path c:\temp\FichierOK.csv -NoTypeInformation

    }
    else
    {
        #ECRIRE DANS LE 5eme FICHIER RECAP AVEC ;KO
    }
}

$DateErrors.ToArray() | Export-Csv -Path c:\temp\DateErrors.csv -NoTypeInformation
$FileNameErrors.ToArray() | Export-Csv -Path c:\temp\FileNameErrors.csv -NoTypeInformation
$CanalErrors.ToArray() | Export-Csv -Path c:\temp\CanalErrors.csv -NoTypeInformation
$NumAssureErrors.ToArray() | Export-Csv -Path c:\temp\NumAssureErrors.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

And as well I would like to catch all the "good treatment and export it" into a csv file like my first csv file with the command :

```
$CsvColonneEnPlus = import-csv -path 'c:\temp\testH.csv' -Delimiter ';' | Select-Object *,@{Name='Etat';Expression={'OK'}}
```

It works but I don't know where in the code to put it in to catch the right values

Here the result I'm obtaining (which catch everything)

```
"UCB63_DATENUM","U6618_FILENAME","UF6E8_CANAL","U65B8_IDRP","Etat"
"08/07/201","457E6659_ZN_LIQRLVPR_A_V_ML.pdf","ML","","OK"
"11/09/2019 22:04","49453878_ZN_LIQRLVPR_A_V_ML.pdf","ML","106440","OK"
"24/09/2019 00:00","497E585B_ZN_LIQRLVPR_A_V_CS","CS","1536658","OK"
"12/02/2020 00:00","","ML","1406091","OK"
"","3D517878_ZN_LIQRLVPR_A_V_ML.pdf","ML","1282640","OK"
```

Comment: looping through here string datas seems impossible

Comment: Does your CSV file always have headers?

Comment: Do you need to validate the date, or just make sure it's a date-like string?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your requirements correctly, I think the code below should give you the basic logic. It will be up to you to figure out what work needs to be done for each `if` statement.

```
$liste = Import-Csv -path '.\test.csv' -Delimiter ';'
[System.Collections.ArrayList] $DateErrors = @()
[System.Collections.ArrayList] $FileNameErrors = @()
[System.Collections.ArrayList] $ThirdColumnErrors = @()
[System.Collections.ArrayList] $FourthColumnErrors = @()
    
foreach($item in $liste)
{
    $date = $($item.UCB63_DATENUM -split " ")[0]
    if($date -notmatch "[0-9]{1,2}[\/][0-9]{1,2}[\/][0-9]{1,2}") { $DateErrors.Add($item) }

    if($item.U6618_FILENAME -notmatch ".+[\.]pdf") { $FileNameErrors.Add($item) }
    
    if([System.String]::IsNullOrEmpty($item.UF6E8_CANAL)) { $ThirdColumnErrors.Add($item) }
    
    if([System.String]::IsNullOrEmpty($item.U65B8_IDRP)) { $FourthColumnErrors.Add($item) }
}

$DateErrors.ToArray() | Export-Csv -Path .\DateErrors.csv -NoTypeInformation
$FileNameErrors.ToArray() | Export-Csv -Path .\FileNameErrors.csv -NoTypeInformation
$ThirdColumnErrors.ToArray() | Export-Csv -Path .\ThirdColumnErrors.csv -NoTypeInformation
$FourthColumnErrors.ToArray() | Export-Csv -Path .\FourthColumnErrors.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Why use regex for either option? $item.EndsWith() will validate the .pdf requirement and Get-Date $item.UCB63_DATENUM will validate the date.

Comment: @RobbieCrash I wasn't aware of the `.EndsWith()` function, and an unjustified distrust of parsers

Comment: @HadrienBeaujean where you see `Write-Host ***` you need to replace that with the work to create/append a csv

Comment: @HadrienBeaujean my edit should get the results you're looking for

Comment: @HadrienBeaujean the logic I used will also detect an empty cell

Comment: @jonathan : sorry i didn't see your solution and it works well outside my loop, i'll try to implement the logs inside (pray for me)

Answer (score 0):

If your CSV file always has headers you can validate each value on each row as you move. That way you can do away with all your min/max calculation and while looping and just deal with a pre-validated (in terms of length) array within PS.

So something like:

```
$Liste = Import-CSV -Path .\file.csv -delimiter ";"
Foreach ($ListItem in $Liste){
    try {$ItemDate = get-date $ListItem.UCB63_DATENUM -EA Stop}catch{write-error "fail"} # Validates this is an actual date
    if (-Not ($ListItem.U6618_FILENAME).endswith(".pdf"){Write-Error "Fail, not a pdf";break} # Makes sure filename ends with .pdf
    if ($null -eq $ListItem.UF6E8_CANAL){Write-Error "Item is empty.";break}
    if ($null -eq $ListItem.65B8_IDRP){write-error "Item is empty.";break}
    # < Do the rest of your work here, after you've validated the input data>
```

This way you build your list, then validate each item before building your output.

If you want to still structure your output filename to match the item in the list you can get the index of your item (assuming each is unique) by using something like the following for your filename:

`$XMLFile = "C:\Temp\TestHH_$($Liste.IndexOf($ListItem)).xml`

You can also then do away with a bunch of your additional variable creation and do it inline, for example:

```
$RecupDateFinTraitement = (Get-Date).ToString('dd-MM-yyyy')
$RecupDateFin30 = (get-date 
$RecupDateFinTraitement).AddDays(30).tostring('dd-MM-yyyy')
```

Comment: Sorry, this posted before I saw that you need to actually do something with the errors. For that, just add in a catch for the error you receive instead of a break when the test fails. The array building in the other answer is a great way to do this.

Comment: It depends on what you need with the data. Do you care about the rest of the row after you've found one piece of invalid data, or do just want to move on to the next row? Personally, if I get garbage data, I don't want to see how bad the data is, I send it back. With my approach, as soon as something fails you move on to the next. With the date check, if Get-Date can't make a date of it, it fails, which will catch empty entries as well, each of your date samples validate properly, and can be converted to dd/MM/yyyy. If you care about each bad entry, you'll need to do each check before exiting.